# The difference between using <html:form> and <form> to submit requests in Java Web Applications

Tags: java, html, struts, apache-tiles

I am learning to use Struts 1.2 and Apache Tiles (I know they are outdated, but for reasons I need to learn their outdated versions) in java dynamic web projects with maven configured in. I'm trying to add a login form as a dropdown menu in my header.jsp file. When I use the code below as a seperate jsp, it works just fine and sends the email and password information to the action servlet, which calls my action and form classes to deal with said info.

```
<html:form action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/login-action.do">
        Email: <html:text name="calisanAraForm" property="email"/>
        Password: <html:password name="calisanAraForm" property="password"/>
        <input type="submit" name="job" value="ara" />
</html:form>
```

But when I want to put said code sniplet into my header, my header disappears from the webpages it is called from (my header.jsp works fine otherwise as it is introduced as a tiles parameter). So because of this, I tried to make a login form using  and  instead of html:form or html:text. The form is like this:

```
<form class="login-form" action="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/login-action.do" method="get">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email"> 
        <input type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" > 
        <input type="submit" name="job" value="ara" />
</form>
```

When I use the above code, the header seems fine. I enter the email and password, click the submit button and I get the error "java.lang.NullPointerException". Full error below:

> **Message**: java.lang.NullPointerException
>
> **Description**: The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> **Exception**:
>
> **javax.servlet.ServletException:** java.lang.NullPointerException
>       org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:286)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       com.chemorbis.web.tiles.TilesDecorationFilter.doFilter(TilesDecorationFilter.java:402)
>
> **Root Cause**:
>
> **java.lang.NullPointerException**:
>       org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.createActionForm(FormBeanConfig.java:289)
>       org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.createActionForm(FormBeanConfig.java:357)
>       org.apache.struts.chain.commands.CreateActionForm.execute(CreateActionForm.java:92)
>       org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
>       org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
>       org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
>       org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
>       org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>       org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:449)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
>       javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
>       org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       com.chemorbis.web.tiles.TilesDecorationFilter.doFilter(TilesDecorationFilter.java:402)

This error also happens before the servlet dispatches the request into my action or form classes, as the console does not include any of the info I am getting it to write out in those classes. What might be the problem? I will include my servlet info from web.xml just to see if I'm missing out on anything.

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>config</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/struts-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>action</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

The url pattern is like this when I click on the submit button:

http://localhost:8080/oyuncak-web-tiles/login-action.do?email=trump%40usa.com&password=mexica&job=ara

Comment: maybe you can open a popup window instead of drop down, as struts form works just fine in popups, maybe struts has been obsolete and does not supports newer browser compatibility

Comment: @MuhammadQasim All it does is render HTML.